# Laravel 5.4 No visit, no action TestCase UnitTest

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-5, controller, testcase

I am trying to get just a basic unitest working according to the Laravel Specification here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/testing#calling-routes-from-tests

I don't seem to have $this->action, I don't seem to have $this->visit. Basically every example that I could find doesn't work. Like WTF.

I just need to test 1 method in my Controller. That's it. No, not through http request, just the method itself.

Can somebody point me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong?

Cheers,

Digital Human

Comment: You are looking into the wrong docs version. Check here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/testing